# how to get url from curl?

Tags: php, curl

I want generate link with tusfile

I have a premium account

this my code

```
$request_url = 'https://www.tusfiles.net/bitbh7nh0wg';
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://www.tusfiles.net/?op=login&login=XXXXX&password=XXXX');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookie.txt');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$store = curl_exec($ch);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $request_url);
$content = curl_exec($ch);
$regex='|<a.*?href="(.*?)"|';
    preg_match_all($regex,$content,$parts);
    $links=$parts[1];
    foreach($links as $link){
        echo $link."<br>";
    }
    curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: `echo $content;` returns what?

Comment: not work echo $content;
I want return link download